# .pls with SafariMobile no more works on iPhone OS 3.1.2?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Are you able to play a .pls with SafariMobile on iPhone OS 3.1.2 ?

ex : http://www.somafm.com/startstream=groovesalad.pls

Thanks

Thierry

Comment: It's not clear to me from your question: are you asking if this works, or trying to say that it *used* to work, and no longer does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
Plug-in was disabled in settings.

Answer (score 1):

I typed what you have above into Safari and it did not work.

I manually visited http://www.somafm.com/startstream=groovesalad.pls and found it does a redirect to http://somafm.com/startstream=groovesalad.pls

So I then tried typing somafm.com/startstream=groovesalad.pls into Safari and it worked.

The redirect might be new behavior on part of SomaFM causing the problem or the problem might be caused by the latest iPhone OS version.